# R Language: Error in read.table(file.path(data.dir, file_name1)) : no lines available in input

Tags: r, import

I am having a hard time coding in R language. What I am trying to do is read large amount of data in to one data frame, and make pretty pictures.

This is what I have:

```
# assign data
file_name1<-"data1_txt"
file_name2<-"data2_txt"

data.dir<-"/...../Documents/R programing Language/"

for(i in 1:length(1)){
    newData1<-read.table(file.path(data.dir, file_name1))

    #Replace negative numbers with NA
    xx <- which(datavalues<0)
    datavalues[xx] <- NA    

    newData2<-read.table(file.path(data.dir,file_name2))

}
```

Error I have is:

> Error in read.table(file.path(data.dir, file_name1)) : 
>    no lines available in input

I am trying to figure out by myself, but I am very new to R language, and I don't have enough knowledge of functions in R. Please explain what this error means and advice on my coding.

Thank you very much,
Uka

Comment: I would start by only trying to read a single file in, perhaps `data1_txt` to start. I would start by understanding where your R session thinks it currently is in your directory with `getwd()`, I would then navigate to the directory of choice with `setwd()`. Once you think you are there, see what files are in that directory with `dir()` or `list.files()`. Iterate with `getwd()` and `setwd()` until you get to the right directory. Then simply read it in with `read.table()` and avoid complicating things with the for-loop and `file.path()` et al. Make sure file names are right. No extensions above

Comment: You may have thought of that already but just to be on the safe side: Are you sure that "data1_txt" is really your complete file name? Windows may be hiding the extension.

Comment: @Chase 
Thanks for your comment. I tried to read one file, but I still have the same error. Do you know anything about loop? I coded loop like:
for(i in 1:length(1))
but I am not sure length(1) is right........

Comment: Loop: You can check whether your "loop" works, with `for( i in 1 : length( 1 ) ) print( i )` - so this seems not to be the problem

Comment: That `for(i in 1:length(1))` "loop" is quite pointless.

Comment: I guess we need some real data...

Comment: @vaettchen I tried to put data but data is really huge, so I couldn't.

Comment: @daroczig for this project I have to use loop. Why is it pointless for this? Can you explain?

Comment: @Uka: as there is no loop. You run your commands once, see: `for(i in 1:length(1)){print(i)}`. But to be ontopic, please check the result of `file.path(data.dir, file_name1)` in your R session and on your filesystem if the file really exists.

Comment: @darozig, I checked file.path(data.dir, file_name1) and it exists and I am directing right file. Do you have any other idea that I can try to fix this error?

Comment: @Uka: I just cannot think any other problem besides: path issue OR your file is empty. Ah, and remove the trailing slash from `data.dir` and please double check if other parts of that directory is OK. (I do not know which platform you use but `/.....` looks interesting)

Comment: @Uka what happens if you type `dir("/...../Documents/R programing Language/"`?

Comment: I'm a Mac guy, but if you're on Windows, I think the newData <- read.table(file.choose()) idiom might simplify things here. [I'm pretty sure this is a Windows only functionality so I can't verify]

Comment: The path looks pretty weird to me; can you try specifying the entire path there (e.g. if you're on Windows, "C:\path\subPath\filename,ext")... or if you're not on Windows, something similar. Also, look at the case of the characters in the path... should the 'p' in 'programming' be capital?

Answer (score 0):

Similar situation was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613270/how-to-fix-the-error-in-r-of-no-lines-available-in-input/13613372#13613372) with similar question (I know this post is quite old). Recently I got such error parsing several files... The reason was some files were empty which makes sense of error message.

Anyway, just make sure your input will not be empty using `try` ou `trycatch` as suggested on mentioned [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613270/how-to-fix-the-error-in-r-of-no-lines-available-in-input/13613372#13613372).