# How to fix the error in R of "no lines available in input"?

Tags: r, url

What I need to do is to read data from hundreds of links, and among them some of the links contains no data, therefore, as the codes here:

```
urls <-paste0("http://somelink.php?station=",station, "&start=", Year, "01-01&etc")
myData <- lapply(urls, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = '|')
```

an error pops up saying "no lines available in input", I've tried using "try", but with same error, please help, thanks.

Comment: the comment in the last question was asking for the contents of `urls`, as I suspect that is where the error lies.   Can you please type in `dput(urls)` and copy+paste the output here.

Comment: Have yo tried @GSee's suggestion?

Comment: when exactly do you see the `"no lines available in input"` error?  Right after the `myData <-...` line?   If not, does myData get some input, just not the correct ones?  (please see my answer below, and let us know if it is in the right direction).   Also, what specifically happens when you try GSee's suggestion?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are 2 possible solutions (untested because your example is not reproducible):

Using `try`:

```
myData <- lapply(urls, function(x) {
  tmp <- try(read.table(x, header = TRUE, sep = '|'))
  if (!inherits(tmp, 'try-error')) tmp
})
```

Using `tryCatch`:

```
myData <- lapply(urls, function(x) {
  tryCatch(read.table(x, header = TRUE, sep = '|'), error=function(e) NULL)
})
```

Comment: @Rosa, you can get rid of the nulls in the list using `is.null`:     <BR>        `myData <- myData[!sapply(myData, is.null)]`

Comment: @Rosa, `Filter(NROW, myData)` will only keep components that have at least 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
  dims <- sapply(myData, dim)[2,]
  bad_Ones <- myData[dims==1]
  good_Ones <- myData[dims>1]
```

If `myData` still grabs something off the station page, the above code should separate the `myData` list into two separate groups.  `good_Ones` would be the list you would want to work with.  (assuming the above is accurate, of course)

Comment: I don't think you want that comma after the 2, but I don't think you want `sapply` either.  Maybe `Filter` would be better, but it's not clear what problem we're trying to solve. ;)

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta, GSee's answer got the exactly results as I want, I guess the empty data resulted in an error and thus stopped the lapply function, and now it moved forward as we set it to NULL. Anyway, thanks for your help, appreciated! :)

Comment: @Gsee, going off the (non-)table that was posted in the comments, `read.table` was bringing in the whole contents as a single column, whereas the correct tables have several columns.  I was using dim to identify which have only one column. sapply puts the first row as the 1st dimension of dim, second row as 2nd dimension, etc.. Hence the comma ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is really an answer to a different issue with the same error message bringing me here.  For me, my Dropbox had stored the folder offline and R couldn't load them in.  So I changed the folder storage to local.