# Reading a csv file from aws datalake

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to read a csv file from aws datalake using R.

I used the below code to read the data, unfortunately I am getting an error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,  :    no lines available in input

I am using the below code,

```
aws.signature::use_credentials()
c<- get_object("s3://datalake-1/x-data/")
cobj<- rawToChar(c)
con<- textConnection(cobj)
data <- read.csv(con)
close(con)
data
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file is not present at the address/URI provided. Unable to reproduce this error so, maybe look for your CSV's correct location.

Apart from that I'd also put the read statement within `tryCatch` as referenced in an already existing answer [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613270/how-to-fix-the-error-in-r-of-no-lines-available-in-input)